# How to get the index of a row in a dataset?

Tags: c#

I am looping through a dataset with a `foreach` loop trying to remove the rows which don't have their ID matched with the assigned value to an array, and I would like to get the index of the current row within the `ds` dataset to remove the row. For example:

```
for(int i =1;i<=TotalWinners;i++)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
    {
        if (dr["ID"] != Winners[i, 0])
        {
            //int x = ds.Tables[0].Rows.IndexOf();
            int index = ds.Tables[0].Rows.IndexOf[current row index]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the index of that row in the loop? And if I can't get the index of that row, how can I select and remove the row by the ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of collection do not allow to change the content (delete) while iterating through foreach. You can simply use for loop instead of foreach if you want to delete the row. You can for more in MSDN article Delete Rows in a DataTable [How to: Delete Rows in a DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13.aspx)

```
for (int i=0 i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) 
{
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"] != Winners[i, 0])
    {
         ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].Delete();
    }        
}
ds.AcceptChanges();
```

[IEnumerator Interface wont allow changes like adding, modifying, or deleting elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx)

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably
>   invalidated and the next call to MoveNext or Reset throws an
>   InvalidOperationException. If the collection is modified between
>   MoveNext and Current, Current returns the element that it is set to,
>   even if the enumerator is already invalidated.

Its worth to look at [DataSet.AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) method that will commit the changes made in `DataSet`.

Comment: @Ali, you can do that like ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"]